# eloquent-sluggable uniqueness test by relationship id

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, slug

I try to use cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable in Laravel (5.4). I have a Page model and a website model. It's using sluggable in the Page model. Now, if i create a page i want tot check for uniqueness by the columns website_id and slug before generating a slug (with -1 or -2 after the title for example). It looks like i should use the method "customizeSlugEngine", but it isn't called when i add it to the Page model.

When it's working i need to find page by slug and page id. In my pageController (front-end) i use:

```
Page::findBySlug($slug);
```

How can i find pages by slug and webiste_id?

Comment: does this work? Page::where('website_id', '=', $website_id)->findBySlug($slug);

Comment: Thanks, with your input and the documentation from the package I solve this with: Page::whereSlug($slug)->where('website_id', '=', $website_id)->first();

Comment: Nice you got it, post the answer to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the comments and answers.

First, i was making a mistake in the first part of my question. I did a custom validation in Laravel on a unique slug, without website id. I changed this and it's works fine.

```
'slug' => 'unique:pages,slug,NULL,pages,website_id,'.\Request::get('website_id'),
```

The model needs the function "scopeWithUniqueSlugConstraints" to check for multiple columns before generating.

```
public function website()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Website');
}

public function scopeWithUniqueSlugConstraints(Builder $query, Model $model, $attribute, $config, $slug)
{
    $website = $model->website;
    return $query->where('website_id', $website->getKey());
}
```

In my pageController (front-end) I call the page with:

```
Page::whereSlug($slug)->where('website_id', '=', $website_id)->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Alternatively you can use str_slug if you just want to sluggify

```
$title = str_slug("Laravel 5 Framework", "-");
//gives laravel-5-framework
```

MODEL

```
class News 
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'body', 'slug',
    ];
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function store(Request $request) 
    {
    $news = new News();
    $news->title = $request->input("title");
    $news->body = $request->input("body");
    $news->slug = str_slug($request->input("title"));//you can append current date and time to make unique slug

    $news->save();

}

/**
 * Display the specified news by slug.
 *
 * @param  $slug
 * @return Response
 */
public function ShowbySlug($slug)
{
    $news = News::where("slug",'=',$slug);

    return view('news.show', compact('news'));
}
```

ROUTE

```
Route::get("news/{slug}","NewsController@ShowbySlug");
```